# How can I save child in an existing parent when doing a POST request?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to perform a POST request to save a child (Chapter) onto the parent (`User`), but it does not work.

All other request work fine. `PostMapping` controller saves the `Body` into the database but not with the parent relationship (Class Chapter → `user_id = null` in my case).

I am using the following URL in Postman:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/chapters?username=admin
Content-type: application/json
Body: raw
```

with this body:

```
{
    "name": "Product Development", 
}

Username: "admin" with Id= 1
```

---

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String username;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String password;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String role;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
private Set<Chapter> chapters = new HashSet<>();

public void addChapter(Chapter chapter) {
    this.chapters.add(chapter);
    chapter.setUser(this);
}
....
}

@Entity
public class Chapter {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long id;
    private String name;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
....

}

@RestController
public class ChapterController {
@Autowired
private ChapterRepository chapterRepository;

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;


@RequestMapping("/chapters")
public Iterable<Chapter> getChapter() {
    return chapterRepository.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping(value="/users/{id}/chapters", method = RequestMethod.GET)
Chapter getChapter(@PathVariable (value = "id") Long id) {
    return chapterRepository.findByUserId(id).get();
}

@PostMapping("/chapters")// issue is here
void newChapter(@RequestParam (value = "username", required=true) 
String username, @RequestBody Chapter newChapter) {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    user.addChapter(newChapter);
    System.out.println(user);
    userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

What I would expect is to save the child with the parent which means with `user_id = 1`  as there is only one user for now (`id = 1`). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add cascading for your `@ManyToOne` mapping.
Update this line in your User `@Entity` and it will work:

```
@Entity
public class Chapter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

}
```

The second thing you might want to do, is updating your controller, so it assigns user id to your new chapter, just like this:

```
@PostMapping("/chapters")// issue is here
void newChapter(@RequestParam (value = "username", required=true)
                        String username, @RequestBody Chapter newChapter) {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    newChapter.setUser(user);
    user.addChapter(newChapter);
    System.out.println(user);
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried but it still does not work. User_id is still null in the database.... :(

Comment: @willingis, please check my edit. It should be fine now

Comment: Unfortunalty, it still not good but thank you again! I think my issue is not there because when I save my first user I am able to link the child with the parent with that code:   user.addChapter(newChapter).

Comment: @willingis, you can always try to use chapterRepository to save chapters:
`chapterRepository.save(newChapter);`

Comment: @ ilya, I already tried but it sill does not work. When i start my application, I create an user with username=admin and a chapter. Then, I appply this method: user.addChapter(chapter) to finally save the user userRepository.save(user);. All of this work but not in my post resquest.... Any idea?

Comment: @willingis, try adding logs or using the debugger, to make sure the user is found and modifying queries are executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the `user` entity in `newChapter.user` field. Because it's the `Chapter` Entity which owns the relationship.

The `cascade` method in `OneToMany` annotation only specifies  which operations must be cascaded. It doesn't mean that the `user` property of `Chapter` entity will be set automatically.

Comment: Indeed, I through that as well and I tried to set User in the newChapter before saving it but it does not seem to work this way. There is something which I am missing... But I am gonna try to work with logs and see in more detail what is happening then... thanks for replying